# Cannot implicitly convert DialogResult to MessageBoxResult

Tags: c#, wpf

I am receiving the error 'Cannot implicititly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to System.Windows.MessageBoxResult'

At first I thought this was just a missing import so I put imported System.Windows.Forms but it came to no avail as doing this throws up an error on my actual message box which is 'MessageBox' is an ambigous reference between 'System.Windows.MessageBox' and 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' (Which isn't to hard to figure out :P) but the original message remains the same.

```
    private void DisplayOnWebsiteChecked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var departments = model.Name;
        var departmentChildren = model.Children;

        var messagebox = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to hide all sub deparments and products.",
             "List of Box",
             MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

        if (messagebox = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (departmentChildren != null)
            {
                int zeroChildren = 0;

                if (departmentChildren.Count.Equals(zeroChildren)) ;
                 {
                    foreach (Department Children in departmentChildren)
                        Children.IsVisibleOnWebsite = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return;
    }
```

I have included the whole method just incase you need anything from it.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're *trying* to write a Windows Forms app (in which case you should get rid of the import for System.Windows.Forms) or a WPF app (in which case you should be using System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.)

Comment: Apologies, I should of tagged it better. This is just a dialog box for my WPF application.

Comment: Then why were you trying to use System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult?

Comment: Use == (equals) ... not = (assignment)

Comment: You're mixing the WPF MessageBox with the WinForms DialogResult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you've now explained that this is a WPF app, if you're using [`System.Windows.MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.show.aspx) you should be comparing against [`System.Windows.MessageBoxResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx).

Basically, if you're doing WPF you almost certainly don't want *any* mention of `System.Windows.Forms`, and vice versa. (I'm surprised this was compiling at all - do you have references to both assemblies? That's generally a bad idea...)

Additionally, you need to use `==` for comparisons, not `=` (assignment)

```
var result = MessageBox.Show(...);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) All works well, sorry for being very ambiguous on my initial question!

Answer (score 3):

I think you've got your Windows Forms and WPF mixed up - if you're using the [WPF MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx) then your return value is different.

So it's not

```
messagebox = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
```

It's

```
messagebox == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes
```

Note also the `==` otherwise you're assigning the value, and the if test will always succeed (with a compiler warning).

Answer (score -1):

You're problem is here:

```
  if (messagebox = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
```

First, you're assigning a `DialogResult` into a `MessageBox`.  Secondly, you're attempting to compare a `DialogResult` with a `MessageBox`.  Try something like:

```
if(MessageBox.Show("Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Or you can assign the DialogResult into its own variable, and compare that.

Comment: Probably a typo, but you're still comparing to a DialogResult in your answer.

Comment: Not a typo.  This actually works.  It compares the selected result with the comparator.  The OP was looking to compare the `DailogResult`.  He was just going about it wrong.

Comment: No, this does NOT work. It throws a compiler error: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.MessageBoxResult' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult'. Also, you're MessageBox.Show method parameters are a little off so there's no way you compiled that line. The only way it can work is if you were to cast both operands to 'int' like this: if((int)MessageBox.Show("Message", "Caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == (int)DialogResult.Yes)

Comment: With that being said, you still shouldn't mix WPF with WindowsForms, as [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) pointed out in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12711385/1575237). Not when all you have to do is change DialogResult to MessageBoxResult

Comment: @bugged87: I do apologize.  I actually used `if(MessageBox.Show("Message", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)`, and that does work.  That said, I agree you shouldn't mix.  I again was only trying to fix what the OP was posting.

Comment: I just realized you were using the [MessageBoxButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx) (with an 's') which is in the WinForms assembly, and I was using the [MessageBoxButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxbutton.aspx) (without an 's') which is in the WPF assembly. That would explain the compiler error I was seeing.

Comment: Since the user is using WPF, and can't mix `Windows.System.MessageBox` with `Windows.System.Forms.MessageBox`, you can't use `DialogResult` at all, since that is in `Windows.System.Forms`.  If you try to import `Windows.System.Forms`, you get a red squiggly under `MessageBox.Show` that says it is ambiguous whether you are using `Windows.System.MessageBox` or `Windows.System.Forms.MessageBox`.  Only the latter has access to `DialogResult`.  The former is what WPF will force you to use, since you have to have a reference to `Windows.System` by default.  Must use `MessageBoxResult`.